# Sox - Automator Folder Action with Shell Script to batch normalise audio files

Tags: shell, automator, sox

I'm trying to create an Automator Folder Action that normalises (to -3dB) any audio file placed in "Folder A" and moves it to "Folder B".

The following in Terminal achieves the desired result:

Step 1.

```
cd /Users/ray/Desktop/Folder\ A
```

Step 2.

```
for file in *.aif; do sox $file --norm=-3 /Users/ray/Desktop/Folder\ B/$(basename $file) -V; done
```

Basically, how do I convert this process into a Folder Action?

In Automator I've tried:

Choosing "Folder A" as the input and entering the code in Step 2 into a Run Shell Script. I get the following error "sox command not found". I'm assuming this indicates there is a problem with where sox is installed (which I did using HomeBrew). A search in Finder shows the sox folder here:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/sox
```

I've tried various commands to set the path to the sox application. Nothing worked.

There may be other problems contributing. I'm not sure what to set "Shell" to, or "Pass input" to, or whether to leave the default text that appears when a selection is made e.g. "cat".

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fryv9.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep 'Shell' as '/bin/bash', but set 'Pass Input' to 'as arguments', then paste

```
source ~/.profile

for file in "$@"
do
  bname="${file##*/}"
  sox --norm=-3 "$file" "/Users/ray/Desktop/Folder B/$bname"
done
```

Then things should work, assuming you have a 'Folder B' on your desktop, and sox is on your `$PATH`. If the latter doesn't hold, use the full path to sox as you suggested, or put `/usr/local/Cellar` on your `$PATH`.
I've got my environment setup stuff in `.profile`, so I just source that.

Comment: The Folder Action didn't produce a result so I’m running it as a Workflow to troubleshoot. I’m using a Get Specified Items action with Folder_A added to the list, followed by the Shell Script. I've tried various audio files.

    for file in "$@"
    do
    bname="${f##*/}"
    /usr/local/Cellar/sox/14.4.2_1/bin/sox --norm=-3 "$file" "/Users/ray/Desktop/Folder_B/$bname"
    done

The result is the error message:
/usr/local/Cellar/sox/14.4.2_1/bin/sox FAIL formats: can't determine type of file `/Users/ray/Desktop/Folder_A'

Comment: I've made the correction. This is the code: for file in "$@"
do
  bname="${file##*/}"
  /usr/local/Cellar/sox/14.4.2_1/bin/sox --norm=-3 "$file" "/Users/ray/Desktop/Folder_B/$bname"
done. Still getting the same error.

Comment: Are you using it as a folder action now? I've had some hiccups on my end as well, but never seen that error.

Comment: The error seems to say that you're somehow passing a folder to sox, not a file.